# Rails stuck on post for a long time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Every time  to **POST** a request

it takes me about 10~20 sec to stuck on the console.

What happened ? How to profile it ?

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-01-07 11:20:43 +0800
```

### Here's the gems are suspected to cause the slow response

```
gem 'quiet_assets'
gem "spring"
gem 'pry-rescue'
 gem 'pry-byebug'
```

### development.rb

```
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

--------------
```

Comment: can you please also show us the actual code (not just your settings)?

Comment: likewise - something more meaningful from the logs?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with slow performance, it became worse the larger your assets became.  The solution, was that one line you have set to true in your development.rb file.

> config.assets.debug = true

Change that to **false** and you should see a BIG improvement!